# convertir en link un columna de una tabla que se genera automáticamente con jqery

Tags: html, jquery

Mi tabla se llena automáticamente con jqery y necesito que la columna nombre sea

un link que me direccione a otra pagina no se como resolver este problema si en

jquery o en el html

que puedo hacer algun experto que me de alguna sugerencia

codigo jquery

```
function obtener_productos_exitoso(respuesta) {
reserva_productos = respuesta;
$("#tblProductos tbody tr").remove();
if (respuesta.length == 0) {
    var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
    var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
    celda1.colSpan = '10';
    celda1.style.textAlign = "center";
    celda1.innerHTML = 'Sin datos para mostrar';
} else {
    var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {

        var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
        //fila.style.height = "10px";
        var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
        var celda2 = fila.insertCell(1);
        var celda3 = fila.insertCell(2);
        var celda4 = fila.insertCell(3);
        var celda5 = fila.insertCell(4);
        var celda6 = fila.insertCell(5);

        celda1.innerHTML = respuesta[i].fecha;
        celda2.innerHTML = respuesta[i].nombre;
        celda3.innerHTML = respuesta[i].empresa;
        celda4.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_vendedor;
        celda5.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_potencial;
        celda6.innerHTML = respuesta[i].nombre_cam;
    }
    get_prospecto_amount();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solamente tienes que concatenarle la etiqueta `<a>` a tu valor nombre para que lo tome como tal, y ya solo tendrías que poner tu url:

```
function obtener_productos_exitoso(respuesta) {
reserva_productos = respuesta;
$("#tblProductos tbody tr").remove();
if (respuesta.length == 0) {
    var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
    var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
    celda1.colSpan = '10';
    celda1.style.textAlign = "center";
    celda1.innerHTML = 'Sin datos para mostrar';
} else {
    var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {

        var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
        //fila.style.height = "10px";
        var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
        var celda2 = fila.insertCell(1);
        var celda3 = fila.insertCell(2);
        var celda4 = fila.insertCell(3);
        var celda5 = fila.insertCell(4);
        var celda6 = fila.insertCell(5);

        celda1.innerHTML = respuesta[i].fecha;
        celda2.innerHTML = "<a href='tuURL'>"+respuesta[i].nombre+"</a>";
        celda3.innerHTML = respuesta[i].empresa;
        celda4.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_vendedor;
        celda5.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_potencial;
        celda6.innerHTML = respuesta[i].nombre_cam;
    }
    get_prospecto_amount();
}
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo  "<a href='tuURL'>"+respuesta[i].nombre+"</a>" funciona a la perfección con el detalle del + que se quedo afuera de las comillas

Comment: Tienes razón, pequeño error de dedo. Edito, me alegro que te haya servido.